# try to load powerpoint file but failed

Tags: delphi, powerpoint

After installed MS Powerpoint Viewer, I run the code below

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses     Comobj,
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls,Office_TLB, office97, PowerPointXP;//, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton; 
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  ppShowTypeSpeaker = 1;
  ppShowTypeInWindow = 1000;
  SHOW_FILE = 'C:\Users\myname\Downloads\practicepowerpoint.ppt';
var
  oPPTApp: OleVariant;
  oPPTPres: OleVariant;

  screenClasshWnd: HWND;
  pWidth, pHeight: Integer;

  function PixelsToPoints(Val: Integer; Vert: Boolean): Integer;
  begin
    if Vert then
      Result := Trunc(Val * 0.75)
    else
      Result := Trunc(Val * 0.75);
  end;

begin
  try
  oPPTApp := CreateOleObject('PowerPoint.Application');
  except
    showmessage('no ppt');;
    exit;
  end;
  oPPTPres := oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(SHOW_FILE, True, True, False);
  pWidth := PixelsToPoints(Panel1.Width, False);
  pHeight := PixelsToPoints(Panel1.Height, True);
  oPPTPres.SlideShowSettings.ShowType := ppShowTypeSpeaker;
  oPPTPres.SlideShowSettings.Run.Width := pWidth;
  oPPTPres.SlideShowSettings.Run.Height := pHeight;
  screenClasshWnd := FindWindow('screenClass', nil);
  Windows.SetParent(screenClasshWnd, Panel1.Handle);

end;

end.
```

the line

```
 oPPTApp := CreateOleObject('PowerPoint.Application');
```

causes error.

Just wonder if I have to install Powerpoint rather than Powerpoint Viewer before run the code

Your comment welcome

Comment: Parenting like this doesn't work out. Find a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "Powerpoint.Application" starts Powerpoint. I would not recommend to use the powerpoint viewer because it is a really old program (from 2010 and before). I am not shure if you can automate this program. 
The new way to view pptx is [Powerpoint online](https://office.live.com/start/PowerPoint.aspx)